# is it possible to use a thread consumer / producer at same of time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a set of questions regard consumer/ producer problem..

1. is it possible to make a thread consumer and producer at the same time ?
2. what is the best block queue type for sending/receiving data between threads?
3. is it possible to limit the transmission between threads to set of instances of threads ? and how ?

Thanks.

For question NO 1. I think BlockingDeque is the solution. 
Here is some explanation:http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingdeque.html

Comment: This concurrency pattern is sometimes known as a "worklist"..for instance searching for a specific string in files by recursively exploring a directory could be implemented as keeping a concurrent structure (the work list) to hold the directories that still need to be explored. Each worker thread takes an item from the list, does something with it, and perhaps puts childeren directories back into the work list to be processed by itself or another worker thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. Usually if a thread is both consumer and producer, it consumes different "products" than produces, but it also can consume its own product.
2. Depends on the characteristics of the messages and transfer rate. But usually benefits are negligible.
3. Yes - just pass the queue to the interested parties only.

Comment: for question No.3: what if an instances take two queue path.. one from the queue 1 and the other from queue 2 like router .. between subnets..

Comment: I think "Exchanger" will work in my case for creating a router. Here is an example :http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/exchanger.html

Answer (score 2):

To add to Alexei's answer:

1. While it's possible, note that such thread will have to split it's CPU time between consuming and producing activities, so they can't be run concurrently. But it's perfectly viable, e.g., if your thread accepts some data (takes it from it's consumer-side queue), quickly transforms it somehow and offloads it to the next queue;
2. While `LinkedBlockingQueue` minimizes blocking on producer's side, it's usage may lead to memory exhaustion if consumer works much slower than producer (e.g., consumer do some long-running calculations on producer's input). So, you may want `ArrayBlockingQueue`, which is bounded and, therefore, wouldn't lead to OutOfMemory error.